# Can Rust use a HashMap as a key in another HashMap?

Tags: rust, hashmap

Example:

```
let mut test: HashMap<HashMap<String, String>, String> = HashMap::new();
test.insert(HashMap::from([("test", "test")]), "test");
```

The compiler doesn't like this...

```
error[E0599]: the method `insert` exists for struct `HashMap<HashMap<String, String>, String>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
    |
81  |             test.insert(HashMap::from([("test", "test")]), "test");
    |                  ^^^^^^
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `HashMap<std::string::String, std::string::String>: Hash`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. To use something as a key of a hashmap, it must be hashable. But a hashmap cannot be hashed (which is what the error message is telling you). The reason for this is that there is no straightforward efficient way to do this. You can read more about the rationale in [this discussion](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/implementing-hash-for-hashset-hashmap/3817).

`BTreeMap` can be hashed and have a map-like interface, so you can have `HashMap<BTreeMap<String, String>, String>`.

Comment: Appreciate the link!  In my real-world scenario test is already a HashMap, so I'm needing to convert it to a BTreeMap.  This is what I have that seems to work, but is there a better method?  test.iter().map(|(k, v)| (k.clone(), v.clone())).collect()

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible, because keys in a `HashMap` must implement `Hash`, and `HashMap` does not.  However, `BTreeMap` does, so you could use that, or you could use a `BTreeMap` inside of a `BTreeMap`, like so:

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn main() {
    let mut test: BTreeMap<BTreeMap<String, String>, String> = BTreeMap::new();
    test.insert(BTreeMap::from([("test".into(), "test".into())]), "test".into());
}
```

That works because `BTreeMap` requires its keys to implement `Ord`, and `BTreeMap` itself implements `Ord`.

The practical reason why `HashMap` doesn't implement `Hash` is because `Hash` must be deterministic, since two equal keys are required to have the same hash.  That's difficult to do, though, because, to prevent hash collision complexity attacks, every `HashMap` instance is randomized.  On the other hand, `BTreeMap` is completely deterministic.